# Skip file if csvread fails Matlab

Tags: matlab, file-io, csv, error-handling

So i am reading a bunch of log files. Most of them are good to use with csvread, but some are empty. When you pass an empty file to csvread you get this in return:

```
Error using dlmread (line 139)
Badly formed format string.

Error in csvread (line 48)
    m=dlmread(filename, ',', r, c);

Error in CreateBDTable (line 15)
        digArea = csvread(sprintf('Converted_Logs\\DigAreaPoints\\%s', file2(j).name));
```

Is there a way to catch or prevent this and just skip this file?
Or do i need to do some pre-processing and have a look in the file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like most languages, matlab has a 'try' statement that will allow you to ignore errors.

```
for file = files
    try
        csv = load(file.name);
        % do stuff
    catch err
        % do nothing?
    end
end
```